# Using OpenGL ES to do texture mapping on simple polygons?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping

Intro:
I'm brand new at OpenGL. I first go familiar with texture mapping and basic transformations/translations on OpenGL on my PC.
Now it seems I'm basically re-learning everything as im trying to create a simple polygon (quad) with a PNG texture using the GLKit (the GLKView project template helped alot).

Here's the thing:
I was actually able to get up and running very quickly using the project template's out-of-box implementation using the GLKBasicEffect way of rendering. However, ive read so much in the past 24 hours about the recommendation of ignoring this route and going with "OpenGL ES2" way.
My very general idea of this is basically: fixed-pipeline vs programmable-pipeline. Whatever.

Problem:
When going with the "ES2" approach, I can see my quad polygon, but I'm unable to apply a texture on it.

> Question: Anybody know of a simple tutorial/example I can follow? Or
>   even better, can anybody figure out what im doing wrong?
>
> *** Insert of Update comment ***
>
> > I discovered that i was getting a glError thrown due to two things in
> >     my openGL setup: I was calling glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and
> >     glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY). How am i suppose to
> >     enable texture mapping without these? Or maybe there is a bigger error
> >     somewhere? FYI, I am using Opengl ES2.
>
> *** End of update insert ***

My ViewController file is below.

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))

// Uniform index.
enum
{
    UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX,
    UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX,
    NUM_UNIFORMS
};
GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];

// Attribute index.
enum
{
    ATTRIB_VERTEX,
    ATTRIB_NORMAL,
    NUM_ATTRIBUTES
};

BOOL updateRotate = FALSE;
VertexData *p_meshVertexData = nil;
int g_numFaces = 0;
GLuint g_textures[2]; // 0: photo, 1: picture frame.

const int DataSize = 48;
GLfloat PortraitVertexData[DataSize] =
{
    // CCW
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0,1,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0,0,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1,0,

    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0,1,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1,0,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1,1,

};

@interface ViewController () {
    GLuint _program;

    GLKMatrix4 _modelViewProjectionMatrix;
    GLKMatrix3 _normalMatrix;
    float _rotation;

    GLuint _vertexArray;
    GLuint _vertexBuffer;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) GLKBaseEffect *effect;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GLKTextureInfo *texture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CaptureEngine *engine;

- (void)setupGL;
- (void)tearDownGL;
- (BOOL)loadShaders;
- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file;
- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog;
- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize context = _context;
//@synthesize effect = _effect;
@synthesize texture = _texture;
@synthesize engine;


/// View did load.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    [self initEngine];
    [self setupGL];
}

/// Initialize engine object.
- (void) initEngine
{
    self.engine = [[CaptureEngine alloc] init];

    g_numFaces = DataSize / 8;
    p_meshVertexData = (VertexData *)malloc(g_numFaces * sizeof(VertexData));

    int numIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSize; i += 8)
    {
        float x = PortraitVertexData[i];
        float y = PortraitVertexData[i + 1];
        float z = PortraitVertexData[i + 2];

        float nx = PortraitVertexData[i + 3];
        float ny = PortraitVertexData[i + 4];
        float nz = PortraitVertexData[i + 5];

        float tx = PortraitVertexData[i + 6];
        float ty = PortraitVertexData[i + 7];

        VertexData data;
        data.vertex.x = x;
        data.vertex.y = y;
        data.vertex.z = z;
        data.normal.x = nx;
        data.normal.y = ny;
        data.normal.z = nz;
        data.textureCoord.x = tx;
        data.textureCoord.y = ty;

        p_meshVertexData[numIndex++] = data;
    }

   // UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame.png"];
   // self.previewImage.image = [ImageLoader ConvertToGrayedImage:testImage];
}

// Dealloc.
- (void)dealloc
{    
    [self tearDownGL];

    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context) {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
    }
}

// Memory warning.
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if ([self isViewLoaded] && ([[self view] window] == nil)) {
        self.view = nil;

        [self tearDownGL];

        if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context) {
            [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
        }
        self.context = nil;
    }

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Setup OpenlGL.
- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self loadShaders];

    /*
    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
    self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
    self.effect.lightingType = GLKLightingTypePerPixel;
    */

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexData) * g_numFaces, p_meshVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (char *)12);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (char *)24);


    //// texture sample
  /*
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"frame" ofType:@"png"];

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                                                        forKey:GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft];


    self.texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                       options:options error:&error];
    if (self.texture == nil)
        NSLog(@"Error loading texture: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    */
    /*
    GLKEffectPropertyTexture *tex = [[GLKEffectPropertyTexture alloc] init];
    tex.enabled = YES;
    tex.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeDecal;
    tex.name = self.texture.name;

    self.effect.texture2d0.name = tex.name;
    */

    UIImage *textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame.png"];
    [self ApplyTexture: textureImage];

    //// end of texture sample

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

// Dealloc OpenlGL.
- (void)tearDownGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);

    //self.effect = nil;

    if (_program)
    {
        glDeleteProgram(_program);
        _program = 0;
    }
}

#pragma mark - GLKView and GLKViewController delegate methods

// Update process.
- (void)update
{
    /// Default OpenGL project template (2 cubes) ///

    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    //self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
    baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    /*
    // Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with GLKit
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0, 1.0f, 0);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
    */

    // Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with ES2

    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0, 1.0f, 0);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
    _normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(modelViewMatrix), NULL);
    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);


    if (updateRotate)
    {
        _rotation += self.timeSinceLastUpdate * 0.5f;
    }
}

// Render process.
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    /*
    // Render the object with GLKit
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, g_numFaces);
    */

    // Render the object again with ES2
    glUseProgram(_program);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, g_numFaces);

}

- (int) ApplyTexture:(UIImage *)image
{
    // 1
    CGImageRef spriteImage = image.CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to apply texture.");
        return -1;
    }

    // 2
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);
    GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * width * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));

    CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData,
                                                       width,
                                                       width,
                                                       8,
                                                       width * 4,
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage),
                                                       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    // 3
    CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), spriteImage);
    CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

    // 4
    glGenTextures(1, &g_textures[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textures[0]);

    // glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   // glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);
   // glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(spriteImage));
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, width, 0, GL_RGBA,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CFDataGetBytePtr(data));

    free(spriteData);
    return 0;
}

#pragma mark -  OpenGL ES 2 shader compilation

- (BOOL)loadShaders
{
    GLuint vertShader, fragShader;
    NSString *vertShaderPathname, *fragShaderPathname;

    // Create shader program.
    _program = glCreateProgram();

    // Create and compile vertex shader.
    vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"vsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Create and compile fragment shader.
    fragShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"fsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Attach vertex shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, vertShader);

    // Attach fragment shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, fragShader);

    // Bind attribute locations.
    // This needs to be done prior to linking.
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribPosition, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribNormal, "normal");

    // Link program.
    if (![self linkProgram:_program]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program);

        if (vertShader) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader);
            vertShader = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader);
            fragShader = 0;
        }
        if (_program) {
            glDeleteProgram(_program);
            _program = 0;
        }

        return NO;
    }

    // Get uniform locations.
    uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
    uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "normalMatrix");

    // Release vertex and fragment shaders.
    if (vertShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, vertShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    }
    if (fragShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, fragShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file
{
    GLint status;
    const GLchar *source;

    source = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];
    if (!source) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    *shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Shader compile log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        glDeleteShader(*shader);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
    GLint status;
    glLinkProgram(prog);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program link log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
    GLint logLength, status;

    glValidateProgram(prog);
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program validate log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What is OOB? Not everyone knows every acronym!

Comment: Also, you don't seem to be calling `glGetError()` anywhere. You should call it and check the result to see if OpenGL is unhappy with anything you've done.

Comment: Apologies: "OOB" is Out-of-box. I created a simple opengl app on my PC using the "OOB" opengl library (i didnt have to install anything. Wow!). And for my iPhone openGL app, im using the Project Template that Apple provides thru XCode.

Comment: I placed the glGetError() call right before i call glClear() in my render function. But im not seeing anything. Am i suppose to see something in the console output (if errors exist)?

Comment: @user1118321. Ok, a simple internet search gave me the proper usage for glGetError(). And lo and behold, im getting a "Error uploading texture. glError: 0x0500" !!! Great. now i can narrow things down! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. It looks like glEnable for texture mapping is deprecated.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20656/is-glenable-obsolete-unneeded-in-opengl-es-2

Ugh. I guess i have no choice but to learn this pixel/fragment shader rocket surgery.